# Libpng library Vulnerability rejected by Google Play Store [CVE-2015-8540]

Tags: android, security, libpng

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected XXXX, with package name com.XXX.XXX, for violating our
>   Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   Vulnerability     APK Version(s) Libpng library
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19,
>   v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the
>   issue in this Google Help Center article.     39
>
> To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of
>   your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours to
>   make sure the warning is gone.
>
> While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this
>   software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make
>   sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security
>   issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and
>   Developer Program Policies.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out
>   to our policy support team.
>
> Best,
>
> The Google Play Team

The problem is I didnt include this Libpng, and I dont know which lib I used has it. I checked the dependencies tree, didnt see anything close! How can I locate this file? I have change my whole project from SDK 23 to 24, and Java 1.7 to 1.8, and update all photo related libs to the latest....still I got rejected.**

[Google Libpng Vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127)

```
Dependencies Tree of release
+--- LOCAL: locSDK_6.22.jar
+--- LOCAL: baidumapapi_v3_2_0.jar
+--- LOCAL: easemobchat_2.3.2.jar
+--- LOCAL: libammsdk.jar
+--- LOCAL: fastjson-1.2.7.jar
+--- LOCAL: afinal_0.5.1_bin.jar
+--- LOCAL: jsoup-1.9.2.jar
+--- LOCAL: pinyin4j-2.5.0.jar
+--- LOCAL: umeng-analytics-v5.6.4.jar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
|    \--- com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
+--- cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3
|    \--- com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|              +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|              |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|              |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|              |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|              \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
+--- com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
+--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4
+--- com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0
+--- com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0
+--- com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.1.0
+--- com.bigkoo:pickerview:2.0.8
+--- com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.2
|    +--- com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    +--- me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.4
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |         |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|         |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.1.1.jar
\--- :photogallery-release:

releaseUnitTest
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.556 secs
```

Comment: "I checked the dependencies tree, didnt see anything close!" -- then perhaps you should consider editing your question and posting the dependency tree, in case somebody else might recognize the source of the library. "How can I locate this file?" -- scan your project for files beginning with `libpng`. For example, on Linux, use `find . -name libpng*` from the project root.

Comment: Assuming that one of the dependencies add the libpng file to your apk you should be able to identify the dependency by performing a fulltext search on all files in your local maven repository cache in your user home: `.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your project on the command-line using gradle with debug-logging activated:

```
gradlew -d assembleRelease > logfile.txt
```

Afterwards filter the logfile for the library name and you should be able to identify the source file-name and the library that adds it to your project.